# User Control Properties in designer time

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to create a Visual studio User Control and add options to the designer time menu, for example (Show Previous Page,Show Next page), please see picture

[image]

i'm coding in Vb.net but will accept C# answers too

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to implement a [custom designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973820.aspx). There's an example at the bottom of [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.designerverb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Common properties are more commonly put on the menu attached to the ">" drop down in the upper right.  See `DesignerActionList` which is another type of ControlDesigner

Comment: @Plutonix: OMG, when did they invent that??